# Redux examples - bundle optimization

Tags: webpack, redux, react-redux, webpack-hmr

The redux repository has a set of examples. The problem is that they are for development builds and i'm using them as a template for an app.

This particular example - https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/webpack.config.js
Builds a bundle.js that is 4MB.

I have tried minifying the code, but I can't shrink the size of the bundle. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell if it's bundling React as well? That would be a big addition to the size of the bundle. You can exclude it from the build by adding this to webpack.config.js:

```
externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    }
```

Then you would provide React and ReactDOM separately via another script tag hosted locally or on a CDN.

Comment: That took the bundle down to 2.8 MB which is still incredibly large - I think there's just something about this repo that i dont' understand yet. I checked out another boilerplate that minifies by to less than a MB

Answer (score 0):

You need to [minimize](https://webpack.github.io/docs/optimization.html) and [tree-shake](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/).

**A working example can be found as [redux-auto/example](https://github.com/codemeasandwich/redux-auto/tree/master/example).** You can generate a production bundle by running `npm build` @ 0.27MB **vs** `npm start` @ 1.16 MB = Thats a saving of 420%

The [redux-auto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-auto) example also comes with [hot-reloading](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/03/24/introducing-hot-reloading.html), ES6, React & Redux if you want to use it as a base

If you want to do this in your own project check out [webpack.prod.js](https://github.com/codemeasandwich/redux-auto/blob/master/example/webpack.prod.js) and [.babelrc](https://github.com/codemeasandwich/redux-auto/blob/master/example/.babelrc)